# Migrating Android Studio 0.6.1 to 0.8: [PATH] does not appear to be Android Studio config folder or installation home

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm trying to migrate from the last preview build, 0.6.1 to the new beta, 0.8. I have two Android Studio dirs in my \Program Files\Android\ dir, 0.6.1: \android-studio\ and the new one, \android-studio1\ from 0.8 since you can't upgrade via client from preview to beta. When starting up the exe from 0.8 and prompted to import settings from a previous version of AS from a "config folder or installation home of the previous version of Android Studio" I select  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio" but it complains that the dir "does not appear to be Android Studio config folder or installation home."

Since it doesn't like my installation home path, where is the settings config folder for AS 0.6.1?

EDIT: I've tried the configuration folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\lib\ monitor folders and they don't work either

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ and uses the same config folder.

On Mac OS X the config folder is located at `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview`.

Not sure for Windows but you can look in `C:\Documents and Settings\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.AndroidStudioPreview` or `C:\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.AndroidStudioPreview` according to http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181.

Comment: config directory details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#file_location) for all the OS supported.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac, 
Type the following in the dialog:

```
/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview
```

Answer (score 1):

open android studio 0.6.1 file>export setting>ok

open NEW android studio 0.8.1>import setting>ok

founded the solution!

Answer (score 0):

In Linux it is at `$HOME/.AndroidStudioPreview`